# 20.04.06 freezes for a minute while attempting to shut down

Tags: shutdown, freeze

When I click on Power Off the system freezes for about a minute before proceeding as normal.  This is a Lenovo 14 laptop running Wayland.

**sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e**

```
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: run-snapd-ns.mount: Succe>
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: Unmounted /run/snapd/ns.
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File>
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: Stopped target Swap.
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: Deactivating swap /swapfi>
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-de>
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Dev>
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service:>
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Use>
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: swapfile.swap: Succeeded.
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /swapfil>
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount Al>
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.servic>
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and >
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service:>
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: Finished Power-Off.
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: Reached target Power-Off.
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd[1]: Shutting down.
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesyst>
may 22 23:17:02 gary21-IdeaPad-3-14ADA05 systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM
```

I do not see anything wrong.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was using Bring Out Submenu Of Power Off/Logout Button.  I disabled it and the freeze no longer occurs.